# can't run a jar on one computer but can on another

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I was able to compile a program into a jar file, it only has one class. I had to make a batch file so that I could run the jar without having to use the console directly. The code i used there was `java -cp game.jar game` This allowed me to run the program on my computer with running the batch file. But, when i send the jar and batch file to a friend so he could run it, the console just flashes. I made him install a JRE because I guessed that could have been the problem, but it didn't fix it. My program code is `

public class game {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("|___       ___          ___  __   ___       __   |");
        System.out.println("| |  |__| |__     |    |__  / _` |__  |\\ | |  \\  |");
        System.out.println("| |  |  | |___    |___ |___ \\__> |___ | \\| |__/  |");
        System.out.println("|                                                |");
        System.out.println("|Made by Noah Baker                              |");
        System.out.println("|                                    *Pre-Alpha* |");
        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------+");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("|There once was a fabled legendary item that if  |");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("|placed into the wrong hands could reek havoc.   |");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("|This item could destroy the very fabric of      |");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("|of space and time unless...                     |");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("|unless...                                       |");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        System.out.println("Okay. I'm done with this.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }  
        System.out.println("This \"game\" is nothing even close to one.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }
        System.out.println("Dana, you mean more to me than any game or thing could ever come close to.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        } 
        System.out.println("You are so absoulutely amazing and I am so incredibly lucky to be able to have");
        System.out.println("had you as mine for the past 3 months.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }
        System.out.println("The past three months have been some of the greatest.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }
        System.out.println("I just have one question to ask you.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to go to Homecoming with me?");
        System.out.println("     ******       ******");
        System.out.println("   **********   ********** ");
        System.out.println(" ************* *************");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println(" ***************************");
        System.out.println("   ***********************");
        System.out.println("     *******************");
        System.out.println("       ***************  ");
        System.out.println("         ***********    ");
        System.out.println("           *******      ");
        System.out.println("             ***        ");
        System.out.println("              *         ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) 
        {
        }
    }
{
```

Comment: Does it work for your friend when they run the jar file from the command line (instead of your batch file)? Does he get any error messages in the command line that way?

Comment: *Start* the program with `java` from a stand-alone command line. Read the error message(s).

Comment: good luck on homecoming.

Comment: ... maybe Dana doesn't want to go homecoming with you... just saying...

Comment: Dum, "reek[sic]"should be "wreak"

Comment: You could send the whole jre (32-bit, I guess, to be on the safe side) to your friend, together with your jar and use *it* to run your jar.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your friend to run the batch file from within a command prompt. They should then be able to view (and possibly send you) the error message.

**Error message received from friend**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: game : Unsuported major.minor version 52.0 at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
```

**Advice**

Your friend probably has an older version of the JRE. Compile your code with an older version of Java.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: game : Unsup
orted major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like you compiled the application with a higher version of Java than the JRE that your friend has.

Comment: That was the error that my friend got. I'm guessing i need to take the exception and throw it, right?

Comment: Either ask your friend to install a newer version of the JRE, or compile your code with an older version of Java. See the following which is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error

Comment: I would recommend to compile it in some old version as @Jason mentions. You can't be sure if the person you want to send it to has the most recent JRE.